# Can't load music onto my iPhone 5S with my Mac running 10.6.8

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone

My laptop (a MacBook) runs 10.6.8 and I want to use my iTunes to move my music across to my new iPhone 5s, but the two won't 'talk' to each other.

That is, there seems to be no drag and drop solution, like with other Apple products.

Do you know why, and how I can fix this? Is my laptop too old? Do I need to upgrade?

Comment: Older versions of iTunes do not support newer devices, try updating iTunes first and then upgrade your laptop's Operating System to the latest it can be, and if that still doesn't work, then your laptop wont be able to connect.

Comment: 10.6.8 supports iTunes 11.4 which in turn works just fine with iPhone 5s. What exactly are you trying to do, and what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options for putting music on your iPhone. Manually or Syncing. If syncing is enabled then there's a Music-Section when your iPhone is selected, where you can check playlists, artists etc. that you'd like to sync. Alternatively there's a checkmark that says "Manage Music manually" (or something alike - my system is german). When you can put music on your iPod/iPhone via drag and drop.